# Unable to run on Windows Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a couple of Windows Server 2012 vm's running on AWS. I have installed VS Code on both vm's, however nothing happens when I try to execute VS Code on both. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing several times and have tried both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by VS Code?  Do you have an executable that was built with Visual Studio?  Are you trying to install an instance of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio Code